# Implementing Stacking and Creating a Council in a Local Testnet

Tags: polkadot-js, governance, polkadot-js-extension

how we can implement stacking and made council in local testnet ?

[image][image]

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking of Relay chain staking like Polkadot then you will need the [staking pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/staking).

There is a guide on how to use pallet staking [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3289/29).

If you're looking to have the substrate-node-template be able to stake, then look here:

- [Substrate change node template from PoA to PoS](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/substrate-change-node-template-from-poa-to-pos)

If you want a council, you can use the [collective pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/collective). You can see how Polkadot configures it [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/26b4a21d6ea8d7df343b8f907b12351367e49c45/runtime/polkadot/src/governance/old.rs#L105-L117).

You can also see a basic council configuration [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2577379be50ec2738174d70740c6c3a8d8eb815b/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L994-L1012).